# Java get last element from List of nodes found within PriorityQueue

Tags: java, list, arraylist, nodes, priority-queue

I have been having an issue with the following code:

PROBLEM CODE:

```
Node lastPeek=pq.peek();
tempList3.add(lastPeek.n1.get(n1.size()-1));
```

where pq is a PriorityQueue (storing objects of type Node (see Node class further down), containing objects of `List<Node>` and double type). The PriorityQueue is declared in the following way:

```
Comparator<Node> comparator= new CostComparator();
//creation of priority queue of type Node
PriorityQueue<Node> pq=new PriorityQueue<Node>(comparator);
```

tempList3 (from the PROBLEM CODE section) is an ArrayList with the following declaration:

```
List<Node> tempList3=new ArrayList<Node>();
```

The following is a part of the Node class:

```
public int dest;
    public Node next;
    public Node parent;
    double cost=0;
    List<Node> n1=new ArrayList<Node>();

    public Node(int d) {
        dest = d;
        next = null;
        parent = null;
    }

     //used for storing objects into PriorityQueue pq
     public Node(List<Node> n, double icost) {
        n1=n; 
        cost=icost;
    }
```

As seen in the part of the code described as 'PROBLEM CODE', I have been trying to perform peek() operation on the PriorityQueue pq, of type `<Node>` and storing the value in lastPeek of type Node. The problem arises, when I try to get the last Node within the List value by using .n1.get(n1.size()-1), as n1.size() is not being recognised.

I am getting the error

> cannot find symbol- variable n1

in the .get(n1.size()-1) part. My main aim is to get the first element with PriorityQueue pq, and then getting the List part of this first element, which then allows me to get the last Node value within List (this is why I have been trying to use .get(n1.size()-1) ). The elements in PriorityQueue are being stored in the following structure:

```
Node n=new Node(List<Node> , double);
```

Comment: What do you mean by `"...is not being recognised"`? Are you having a compilation problem? If so, please post the full error message with your question.

Comment: Side issue: why are you using public fields and direct field access in this way? This increases the complexity and connectedness of your code, increasing the risk of bugs.

Comment: I am getting the error cannot find symbol- variable n1 in the .get(n1.size()-1) part. I will do so! @HovercraftFullOfEels

Comment: Well, `n1` isn't public, and so perhaps that's your problem. But having said that, again I advise against making it public, but rather make all the fields private and control access via public methods.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I have tried changing it to public but I still got the same issue. I will try changing them to private as well, even though I doubt it will solve the issue itself in this case. Thanks a lot for your help! :)

Comment: Look at your code again: `lastPeek.n1.get(n1.size()-1)`. The first `n1` is qualified with `lastPeek`, the second is not. Now, why do you think that fails to compile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to defer n1 from lastPeek both time you're using it like this:

```
tempList3.add(lastPeek.n1.get(lastPeek.n1.size()-1));
```